# How to change the dimension of a tensor in tensorflow transform and feed it to trainer?

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, kubeflow, kubeflow-pipelines

I'm working on a data traffic project and my job is to build a pipeline using tensorflow and kubeflow in  Google Cloud Platform.
I've been trying to change the dimension of the examplegen's output in the transform component and use the transform output in the trainer as my model's input. I need to use the data as a tensor in the model but the transform output gets saved as classes.
Here are my "preprocessing" and "features" codes which are part of the transform component.

```
#Preprocessing
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_transform as tft

from models import features
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


def _fill_in_missing(x):
"""Replace missing values in a SparseTensor.

Fills in missing values of `x` with '' or 0, and converts to a dense tensor.

Args:
    x: A `SparseTensor` of rank 2.  Its dense shape should have size at most 1
    in the second dimension.

Returns:
    A rank 1 tensor where missing values of `x` have been filled in.
"""
  if isinstance(x, tf.sparse.SparseTensor):
      default_value = '' if x.dtype == tf.string else 0
      dense_tensor = tf.sparse.to_dense(
          tf.SparseTensor(x.indices, x.values, [x.dense_shape[0], 1]), default_value)
  else:
      dense_tensor = x

  return tf.squeeze(dense_tensor, axis=1)


def preprocessing_fn(inputs):
    """tf.transform's callback function for preprocessing inputs.

    Args:
        inputs: map from feature keys to raw not-yet-transformed features.

    Returns:
        Map from string feature key to transformed feature operations.
    """
    outputs = {} 
    for key in features.DENSE_FLOAT_FEATURE_KEYS:
        # Preserve this feature as a dense float, setting nan's to the mean.
        outputs[features.transformed_name(key)] = tft.scale_to_z_score(_fill_in_missing(inputs[key]))


#   Do not apply label transformation as it will result in wrong evaluation.
    outputs[features.transformed_name(
        features.LABEL_KEY)] = inputs[features.LABEL_KEY]

    return outputs
```

and

```
#features
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

from typing import Text, List, Any

import os
import tempfile
import numpy as np


# At least one feature is needed.

# Name of features which have continuous float values. These features will be
# used as their own values.
DENSE_FLOAT_FEATURE_KEYS = 
['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20',
                       
'21','22','23','24','25','26','27','28','29','30','31','32','33','34','35','36','37','38','39','40',
                        
'41','42','43','44','45','46','47','48','49','50','51','52','53','54','55','56','57','58','59','60',
                        
'61','62','63','64','65','66','67','68','69','70','71','72','73','74','75','76','77','78','79','80',
                        
'81','82','83','84','85','86','87','88','89','90','91','92','93','94','95','96','97','98','99','100',
                        
'101','102','103','104','105','106','107','108','109','110','111','112','113','114','115','116',
'117','118','119','120',
                        
'121','122','123','124','125','126','127','128','129','130','131','132','133','134','135','136',
'137','138','139','140',
                        
'141','142','143','144','145','146','147','148','149','150','151','152','153','154','155',
'156','157','158','159','160',
                        
'161','162','163','164','165','166','167','168','169','170','171','172','173','174','175',
'176','177','178','179','180',
                        
'181','182','183','184','185','186','187','188','189','190','191','192','193','194','195',
'196','197','198','199','200',
                        
'201','202','203','204','205','206','207','208','209','210','211','212','213','214',
'215','216','217','218','219','220',
                        
'221','222','223','224','225','226','227','228','229','230','231','232','233','234',
'235','236','237','238','239','240',
                        
'241','242','243','244','245','246','247','248','249','250','251','252','253',
'254','255','256','257','258','259','260',
                        
'261','262','263','264','265','266','267','268','269','270','271','272','273',
'274','275','276','277','278','279','280','281','282','283','284','285','286','287','288'                            
                        ]


# Keys
LABEL_KEY = '0'


def transformed_name(key: Text) -> Text:
    """Generate the name of the transformed feature from original name."""
    return key + '_x'


def transformed_names(keys: List[Text]) -> List[Text]:
    """Transform multiple feature names at once."""
    return [transformed_name(key) for key in keys]
```

Comment: Hi, I am not sure to have fully understood your issue here. You can [tf.reshape](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/reshape) tensors which might be what you are looking for (as per your title question). However, I am not sure that this is actually your issue here, since you mentioned that "transform output gets saved as classes". Which transform output are you specifically refering to? Also, I believe that some logs here could help to make this case clearer.